# Berlekamp-Massey to construct minimal LFSR

Tags: lfsr

Given the sequence 0010001111 (or any other, not homework, but exam practice), how do you use the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm to construct a minimal LFSR?

I have read several definitions of how Berlekamp-Massey works, but I'm missing some simple example that actually demonstrates the algorithm in use.

Trying to use the following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp-Massey#The_algorithm_for_the_binary_field this is how far (or short) I get:

1. Let $s_0, s_1, \dots, s_9$ be the bits 0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1.
2. Let the arrays b and c, each of length 10, be: b = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, c = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
3. Let L = 0, m = -1
4. Iterate 10 times:

Iteration 0:

$$d = s_0 + c_1s_{-1} + c_2s_{-2} + \cdots + c_9s_{-9}$$

Already at this first iteration (0) I run into problems. What are these negative subscript s variables?

I'm using the formula on Wikipedia, which is:

$$d = s_N + c_1s_{N-1} + c_2s_{N-2} + \cdots + c_Ls_{N-L}$$

Is there a fault in this formula? Earlier at step 3, the algorithm states L = 0, hence the final term with:

$$c_Ls_{N-L}$$

makes no intuitive sense if it is taken literally? I assume that the subscript of this s variable should keep decreasing and for c it should keep increasing? If taken as the formula states it, these would be just 0?

But regardless, there is this problem with the negative s variables.

Comment: Perhaps the explanation in [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5330/819) might help, even though it uses slightly different notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no issues with negative indices, even the first (or zero-th depending
on how you want to count them) iteration.

The quantity $d$ is called the *discrepancy.* During the $N$-th iteration,
$d$ is the *difference* between $s_N$, the $N$-th bit of the given sequence for
which you are finding the LFSR, and the bit computed by the LFSR *that you
have synthesized thus far*.  If $d=0$, the bit produced by the LFSR is
the same as the bit in the given sequence and so the *current* LFSR, which
is guaranteed to produce $s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_{N-1}$, need not be changed:
it is producing $s_N$ also.  On the other hand, if $d \neq 0$, then the
current LFSR needs to be *updated*, that is, you need to find the shortest
LFSR that produces not just $s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_{N-1}$ but *also* $s_N$.
How to go about doing this is the crux of the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm.
Note that it is easy to find **an** LFSR that will produce 
$s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_{N}$:
the trick lies in finding the *shortest* LFSR that will do so.

With that as background, and the further information that $L$ is
an *upper bound* on the number of stages in the *current* LFSR, consider
the discrepancy calculation
$$d = s_N + c_1s_{N-1} + c_2s_{N-2} + \cdots + c_Ls_{N-L}$$
which really ought to be expressed as
$$d = c_0s_N + c_1s_{N-1} + c_2s_{N-2} + \cdots + c_Ls_{N-L}$$
but the simpler version works because $c_0 = 1$ always (see the
initialization).  Now, we begin with $c_0 = 1$ and all other $c_i = 0$, 
that is, a trivial LFSR with no stages that will produce $0$s for 
all eternity if you ask it to.
In the very first calculation when
$L=0$ and $N=0$, we have
$$d = c_0 s_0 = s_0.$$
If you want to use the full-fledged form
$$d = s_0 + c_1s_{-1} + c_2s_{-2} + \cdots + c_9s_{-9}$$
that is fine, as long as you remember that $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_9 = 0$,
and the values you *choose* to
ascribe to $s_{-1}, s_{-2}, \ldots, s_{-9}$ don't affect the computation
at all.  But more realistically, you should note that $L=0$ and $N=0$, and so
the term $c_Ls_{N-L}$ that makes no sense to you is just $c_0s_{0-0}=c_0s_0=s_0$,
just it ought to be.

In the form
$$d = s_N + c_1s_{N-1} + c_2s_{N-2} + \cdots + c_Ls_{N-L}$$
correctly interpreted, you never run out of bits because
$c_{L+1}, c_{L+2}, \ldots$ are all guaranteed to be $0$ and
$L$ is upper bounded by $N$ and so $s_{N-L}$ can reach down
to $s_0$, the leading bit of the given sequence, but no farther.

> There are no negative subscripts on $s$ (or $c$) that we ever need
>   to worry about.