# Linear Feedback Shift Registers analysis

Tags: lfsr

[Cryptanalysis of Linear Feedback Shift Registers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5293/cryptanalysis-of-linear-feedback-shift-registers). From this site I found that lfsr could be break by Berlekamp-Massey algorithm. What is the specific progress of this algorithm? And if there is any other way to do it

Comment: Also, you might be interested in this question [Why are stream ciphers based on linear-feedback shift registers so popular?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66698/18298)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, [LFSR's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) are not secure when they are used alone. They have good statistical properties and one can calculate their period given the feedback polynomial. The LFSR is maximal-length if and only if the corresponding feedback polynomial is primitive. In this case, it visit all states except the all-zero state if it started with a non-zero sate.

To find the taps and internal of an LFSR, you can go in two ways;

1. Give variable names for the internal and tap point then you can generate a linear equation of the system then solve it with Gaussian elimination.
2. Use the [Berlekamp-Massey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm), this is faster than Gaussian elimination and only requires the double of the LFSR's size. i.e. an LFSR with length $L$ can be constructed with $2L$ sequential output regardless of the number of the taps. It is an interactive algorithm that updates the taps according to a currently given output bit.

Actually, Berlakamp-Massey algorithm produces the shortest LFSR with taps that produce the given sequence. The algorithm may reach the result before consuming all $2L$ bits, however, an attacker needs to use all $2L$ bits to be sure. If the determining polynomial of the LFSR is no primitive, then there can be more than one LFSR that produces the sequence with different lengths. Berlakamp-Massey algorithm, however, always will find out the shortest LFSR.

---

The LFSR based archaic stream ciphers are;

- Combining LFSRs with non-linear combiner broken by the novel attack of [Siegenthaler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_attack)
- Irregular clocking as [Alternating step generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_step_generator)
- [Shrinking Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinking_generator) is broken if the taps are known; Gil et. al,  2009 [New Attack Strategy for the Shrinking Generator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0087.pdf)
  if not known then the attacks are not better than brute-force.
- Filtering the LFSR
- [Self Shrinking Generator (SSG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-shrinking_generator). Attack on SSG;

  - 2001 Zenner et. al; [Improved Cryptanalysis of the Self-Shrinking Generator](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-47719-5_4) require less than 70% of the brute-force, for example for 120-bit the attack requires $\mathcal{O}(2^{83})$-time.
  - 2011  Amparo and Sabater; [Cryptanalytic Attack on the Self-Shrinking Sequence Generator](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-20267-4_30) requires $\mathcal{O}(2^{L/2})$ for time complexity, $\mathcal{O}(2^{L/4})$ for the amount of intercepted sequence and $\mathcal{O}(L^2)$. **Note** This work may not be correct, see [comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/77302/how-to-calculate-how-many-generated-sequence-are-needed-to-break-a-specific-lfsr#comment172080_77303)
  - 2006 Zhang and Fang; [New Guess-and-Determine Attack on the Self-Shrinking Generator](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F11935230_4.pdf). Depending on the $L$ the length of the LFSR their attacks has;

    - $L \geq 100$ then $\mathcal{O}(2^{0.556L})$-time complexity, $\mathcal{O}(2^L)$-memory complexcity, and $\mathcal{O}(2^{0.161L})$-bit keystream
    - $L < 100$ then $\mathcal{O}(2^{0.571L})$-time complexity, $\mathcal{O}(2^L)$-memory complexcity, and $\mathcal{O}(2^{0.184L})$-bit keystream

And all the above is broken, at least, theoretically.

Also, some well-knowns due to GSM and Bluetooth.

- [A5/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/1) and [A5/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/2) used in GSM phones, [E0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E0_(cipher)) used in Bluetooth. They are broken, see the links. According to this [source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/technology/by-cracking-cellphone-code-nsa-has-capacity-for-decoding-private-conversations/2013/12/13/e119b598-612f-11e3-bf45-61f69f54fc5f_story.html) NSA can break A5/1.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103895/discussion-on-answer-by-kelalaka-how-to-calculate-how-many-generated-sequence-ar).